# Validate XML against different XSL Versions in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Firstly I've the following code to validate a XML document against a XSD file;

```
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xmld = new XmlDocument();
            xmld.LoadXml(sXML);
            xmld.Schemas.Add(null, sXSDFilePath);
            xmld.Validate(ValidationCallBack);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

I've created a XSD file that will once in production have different versions as and when need features are added.

What is the best way to handle the different versions and ensure that I'm validating against the correct version ?

I initially thought I could include the XSD file and/or version in the XML document, but at this point I wouldn't of validated the XML document.

Comment: Do you mean that for any document D, you will sometimes want to validate against version V1 of your schema, sometimes against versions V2, and sometimes against versions V3 (e.g. at different times in the life cycle of D)?  Or do you mean that your universe of documents will be partitioned into those that are intended to be valid against version V1 of the schema, those that should be valid against V2, and those that should be valid against V3, and that once assigned to V1, V2, or V3 a document will never (or hardly ever) change its allegiance?

Comment: Depending on what XML version is passed, I want to validate it against the correct XSD version; so I can support back compatibility too.

Comment: I think that means the second possibility (each document has a version of the schema it's to be valid against).  In that case, I don't understand why you ruled out the use of xsi:schemaLocation.